# How to integrate the new AD B2C and the C# Azure Mobile Client lib?

Tags: xamarin, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps, azure-ad-b2c

I have secured my API app and I have successfully tested my ADB2C flow with the sample app I found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native. Using that structure, I can trigger the sign-in process, and then access my protected API calls.

However I wanted to also use the WindowsAzure.Mobile sdk as a convenience. It is hinted at here: https://cgillum.tech/2016/08/10/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c-part-2/ that you can trigger the B2C flow from LoginAsync in that class but it does nothing when I call it in that way.

I also found https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/ (scroll to "Authenticate users with the Active Directory Authentication Library") where I substituted the MSAL calls for getting the token. This triggers the sign-on flow, I get a good token and claims back, then I put it in some JSON and pass it like so:

```
AuthenticationResult ar = await App.PCApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.Scopes, "", App.Authority, App.SignUpSignInpolicy, false);
JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = ar.AccessToken;
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(
MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

This call to LoginAsync throws

`{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext () [0x0022f] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
(snip)`

Are they not designed to work together? Are those different kinds of tokens? The reason I'm using B2C is because I really don't WANT to know all that OAUTH stuff :)

Comment: Would you be able to share that LoginAsync call that wasn't working? When you say it does nothing, is the webview appearing at all?

Comment: So the MSAL version of the call pops up the webview and that part works fine. The call to LoginAsync is as per the example code above. But that call to LoginAsync never displayed anything it just returned silently or crashed.

`JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["authenticationToken"] = ar.IdToken;
var user = await mc.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);`

Answer (score 3):

In the case of B2C, you are actually getting back an ID token instead of an access token, and I believe the `ar.AccessToken` property would be null. This property also seems to go away in the latest versions of MSAL.

I suspect you just need to update the payload to "authenticationToken" and instead use `ar.IdToken`.

I am not sure if you can continue to use the "access_token" key in the payload, but it may be that you can. If not, try "authenticationToken" instead.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help. I tried using "authenticationToken" as well as  "authenticationToken" with the ar.IdToken (which is the same value as ar.Token) and those produce a JSON parsing exception down in the guts of the Azure client lib:

 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceAuthentication+<LoginAsync>d__25.MoveNext () [0x0007b] in <filename unknown>:0 

which is opaque to me.

So I think my travels on this are done for a moment. If you have any more ideas - I'd be happy to try them!